# Object and String prototypes are not prototypes of defined strings?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to understand how JavaScript's prototype-based inheritance works. I was expecting the below outputs would evaluate as `true`. Why is this?

```
var myStr = "Sample";
String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr); // false
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr); // false
```

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript has both *primitive* strings and string objects. What you've written there is a primitive string. The [`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.isprototypeof) method always returns `false` for any primitive, so your results make sense.

If you used a string *object*, you'd get `true`:

```js
var myStr = new String("Sample");
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr)); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr)); // true
```

---

You're probably wondering: If it's a *primitive*, then why can I call methods on it that are defined on `String.prototype`?

The answer is that the specification defines that if you use a property accessor on a primitive string, a temporary string *object* with an equivalent character sequence is created (with `String.prototype` as its prototype), and the property is then read from that temporary object. (The same is done with numbers.)

We can prove that the temporary object is created by adding a method to `String.prototype` that returns that object (just for the purposes of illustration):

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "foo", {
  value: function() {
    return this;
  }
});
var primitive = "string";
var object = primitive.foo();
console.log(primitive === object);                      // false
console.log(primitive == object);                       // true
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(primitive)); // false
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(object));    // true
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the [string primitives are not string objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects). If you want the above code to work, the string should be constructed via the `String` class, as in:

```
var myStr = new String("Sample");
String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `isPrototypeOf` only works on objects, and string primitives are not objects, they are primitives.

If you were using the `String` wrapper object, it would work (but don't do that!):

```js
var myStr = new String("Sample");
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr)); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myStr)); // true
```

But the wrapper objects are generally bad practice, so don't use them.

Alternately, you could cast them to their object form when testing.

```js
var myStr = "Sample";
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object(myStr))); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object(myStr))); // true
```